# Processing line graphs in pandas python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a question with line graph processing in python using pandas.
For example, I have an excel file with the corresponding GDP:

```
Year | GDP
2020 | 1000
2019 | 900
2018 | 800
......
1980 | 100
```

Here is my python code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('gdp.csv',encoding='unicode_escape',index_col=0)
df.plot()
```

It shows a graph, but the x-axis shows the years as 1980, 1985, 1990, 1995....2020.

Currently, I want it to print out all the years contained in the excel file ( 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983....). Can anyone just help me? Thank you.

Comment: `df.plot()` is just a convenience function to create a plot using `matplotlib`. The return value of this method is the axis object, which has the method `set_xticks`, which you can use to customize the ticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could work for you:

```
ax = df.plot()
xticks = ax.get_xticks()
ax.set_xticks(range(xticks[0], xticks[-1]+1), labels=range(1980, 2021));
fig = ax.get_figure()
fig.autofmt_xdate()
fig.set_size_inches((16,9))
```

Note, that too many ticks can easily become unreadable, so I used auto formatting to rotate it and increased the figure size.